# Apollo Codegen No operations or fragments found to generate code for

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo, prisma-graphql, apollo-angular

I am trying to setup an apollo project to learn a bit how it works.

I downloaded graphQL nodeJS template from [node-graphql-server](https://github.com/graphql-boilerplates/node-graphql-server)

I setup a simple angular9 application using [apollo-angular](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/)

I run the server, and I wanted to autogenerate the type in my angular app.

I ran the code command

```
apollo codegen:generate --endpoint=http://localhost:500/ --target=typescript --globalTypesFile=./src/app/__generated__/globalTypes.ts

  × Generating query files with 'typescript' target
    → No operations or fragments found to generate code for.
Error: No operations or fragments found to generate code for.
    at write (C:/Users/feder/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache/_npx/3188/node_modules/apollo/lib/commands/client/codegen.js:72:39)
    at Task.task (C:/Users/feder/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache/_npx/3188/node_modules/apollo/lib/commands/client/codegen.js:98:46)
```

I tried to setup some

But I keep getting apollo.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    client: {
      includes: [__dirname+'/src/graphql/**'],
      service: {
        name: "localhost",
        url: "https://localhost:500",
      }
    }
}
```

and played with the command, but I keep getting the same error over and over.

How can I generate the server types ?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar issue when I placed the project inside the folder with the "hash" symbol '#test_folder'. Once I changed that, project was generating as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
"npx apollo client:codegen --localSchemaFile=schema.json --includes=src/**/*.tsx --target=typescript"
```

Comment: try  this in your terminal

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).